# How to extract JSON from URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm looking to extract JSON data from a server URL that looks something like this:

```
https://dev.randomdomain.com/subdomain
```

The URL itself outputs the data like such:

```
[ 
  { "name": "Not configured", 
    "mac_address": "####c##c####", 
    "online": "false", 
    "rate": "Not configured"},

  { "name": "Not configured", 
    "mac_address": "####c##c####", 
   "online": "false", 
   "rate": "Not configured"},
]
```

The outputed data changes and will need to be updated accordingly. I'm wondering what is the best method to retrieve the JSON data from the URL and keep it updated? I've looked at the jQuery getJSON function, and I'm not sure that will work as the URL is simply outputting JSON, it's not a .json file.

Can what I described be done using JavaScript, jQuery or any other open methodology?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this server on the same domain you're making a request from? If not, then `$.getJSON` won't work without using [jsonp](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp).

Answer (score 1):

```
$,getJSON('url',function(data){
     alert(data);
    // or alert("sample text"); would do if the json file is handled well enough.
    // if no alert is shown, it's either you're using chrome with an offline version of 
    // your project or you're having an invalid json file
});
```

May I ask what browser are you using? `$.getJSON` won't work in Chrome if you are doing it in offline mode.

I also got frustrated why the json file not being processed even if I don't use Chrome - e.g. i use FF or IE.

I discovered that you shouldn't put comments inside the json file as it makes it invalid. I think, it's because `.getJSON` really parses data inside the JSON file as text, not as a javascript file, so it will also run through the comment (if you have any), and for sure won't understand it, so I suggest you remove comment block inside your json files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you even tried using `$.getJSON()`? It does exactly what you need it to do, it simply reads the response from the server and returns a json object.

Comment: I have. I setup a test function like such: $.getJSON("https://dev.ethermetrics.net/ForTedOttey", function(data) {
     // do something with the data here
     alert("alert working?");
     
    });  --- However, I can't seem to get the alert to show

Comment: You don't need a semi-colon after the url: `$.getJSON("dev.ethermetrics.net/ForTedOttey", function(data) { alert('Success!'); });`

Additionally, it may be failing for some other reason (invalid json, bad url) so you should check the post via something like Firebug or Chrome's developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're actually trying to parse JSON from a response. The url is the thing you request a response from. Here is a simple example using getJSON:

```
$.getJSON('https://dev.randomdomain.com/subdomain', function(data) {
    var output = "";
    $.each(data, function(index, node) {
        output += node.name + ": " + node.mac_address + "<br/>";
    });
    document.write(output);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YwPzW/1/

Comment: For some reason, none of the getJSON functions actually work. If I copy the json generated by the URL and create a .json file, it works perfectly, but its like getJSON isn't parsing the JSON from the URL. The URL itself is an https, but even when I access it as an http URL it doesn't output. Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem appears to be in how your server is responding. When you visit the URL in the browser, do you get JSON data in return?

Comment: I've been reading and a potential issue that might be causing this is that I'm retrieving the data from a different server from where the script/html file is located. Sugguestions to fix it include using JSONP? is there a way to do that with the code you specified above?

Comment: The server has to participate in that by wrapping the json data in a function call.

Comment: Do you have to consume this data with javascript? It seems an awkward platform given the subject matter.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear from your question if you want to process the data on client side (browser etc.) or on server side for offline processing.

For accessing and processing this data on server side, you can use curl/libcurl to pull data and decode it to an object in language of your choice. For example in php:

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://dev.randomdomain.com/subdomain");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

data_as_php_object = json_decode($output);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is to put *the string in JSON format* into a javascript object. So if you want to get the data, you can try as:

```
$.getJSON("https://dev.randomdomain.com/subdomain",function(data){
   alert(data[0].name);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you trust the source of the JSON string. If you do, just use

```
alert(eval(dropStringHere));
```

The getJSON jQuery method should also work fine.

Comment: It is generally suggested that you use the native `JSON.parse` instead since it also verifies that your JSON is formatted correctly, not to mention for secure purposes.

Comment: @scurker Not all browsers have native JSON parser.